# Serialize with javascript (jquery) to new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to submit a form to with javascript (jquery) to another page that export the result to excel. Below is the code I use to send form data a page and return the results to a div on the same page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function get3() {
 $.post('chartprojecttype.php', 
 $('form[name="reportform"]').serialize(), 
 function (output) {
 $('#info').html(output).show();
 });
 }
 </script>
```

I tried to modify it like this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function get4() {
 $.post('openticketsexcel.php', 
 {
 document.getElementById(‘reportform’).submit();
 });
 </script>
```

But it does not work. I have another way to do this  and have to different pages that export it in different format.

```
  <input type="image" name="excel" onclick="submitForm('openticketsexcel.php')" value="Export To Excel" src="../pix/excel.png" class="submit_button"><input type="image" name="word" onclick="submitForm('openticketsword.php')" value="Export To Word" src="../pix/word.png"class="submit_button">
```

and

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function submitForm(action)
     {
         document.getElementById('reportform').action = action;
         document.getElementById('reportform').submit();
     }
 </script>
```

This works but only in IE.  Chrome and FireFox can used the first code that returns the submitted data but not the code that submits it to the export pages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have MANY issues

1) input type=image is a submit button. Do NOT submit in the onclick of the submit button since you will actually interfere with the event

2) why would you need to submit a form after you post the form to the server? If you need the server to return a word or excel, you need to GET (I GET below by chaning location) or POST a form - but not using $.post since the browser needs to open the file, you cannot ajax word or excel

You likely just want this:

```
<button class="button" id="excel"><img 
alt="Export To Excel" src="../pix/excel.png"/></button>
<button class="button" id="word"><img  
alt="Export To Word" src="../pix/word.png"/></button>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".button").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location="opentickets"+this.id+".php?"+$('form[name="reportform"]').serialize();
  });     
});
```

The simpler solution is just

```
<form action="export.php" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" name="exportformat" value="Excel" />
  <input type="submit" name="exportformat" value="Word" />
</form>
```

and have the php sort things out

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `function` and an ending curly brace, and your single quotes were curly instead of straight. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get4() {
        $.post('openticketsexcel.php', function() {
            document.getElementById('reportform').submit();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is silly. You use jQuery to post a form and then submit a form using DOM when the post is done?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not quite sure what OP wants, so I've left their code alone until they provide more information. I agree though that it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: He want to download word or excel, sees a script that looks cool and applies it to an unrelated situation. Jquery used as a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery post should be like this

```
            $.post( "some/url", function( data ) {
                // code goes here
            });
```

REFERENCE

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: However do NOT use $.post if you want the browser to load a non xml/html/json document